# Mobile caching issue + Php not executing

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, mobile, server

Having a two stage issue that involves every update on my site taking 20 or so minutes to update on mobile devices, but not on desktops. There is no caching plugins, cloudflare, varnish caching or anything. Bluehost doesn't know whats up. My guess has been some sort of cdn for mobile somehow.

Also, some of my php is refusing to execute half the time on mobile. Only happens on the index page, and half the time. The script is valid. Nothing in the logs. It's been some serious scooby doo stuff... Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Updates : 
Beginning to think it's a PHP setting or bug. Possibly Apache.

Updates v2:
nginx seems to be serving up cached php pages. on the phone with the host.

Comment: i dont see how this can be answered by us.

Comment: First and foremost, what is taking 20 minutes to reflect? If it's CSS, or JS, you can add versioning to the file. If you need an example of how this is done, I'll be happy to provide some code. As for your mobile detection script working, or not, we don't have access to the content of Mobile_Detect.php. The code you've shown us would perform a redirect on the homepage, if the script itself is written correctly. To my last question -- why would you have a mobile site? My recommendation is to make your site responsive. Google favors responsive sites, and mobile specific sites are less effective.

Comment: Yes, I understand the desire for responsive. Unfortunately at this point in time it's not a solution. ANYTHING takes 20 minutes to reflect. JS, CSS, PHP, HTML.

Comment: it would make sens for a mobile browser to be far more aggressive at caching than a pc

Comment: @nogad it would, but this isn't the browser.

Comment: then its the mobile app not the php

Comment: @nogad it turns out it's xginx serving cached content.

Answer (score 0):

Check what headers your site is sending, you can clearly see if browsercaching is enabled or not. But it is possible that your host is using a caching server like varnish too to accelerate the speed of your site. 
With the default varnish config enabled you can see in the website-headers if varnish is active or not.

For wordpress there [is a plugin to flush the varnish cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/) which works really great.